# Getting runtime error

Tags: java, string

I am trying to build a very basic program in java to print all the unique characters from the string but I am getting runtime error.

```
Input - amanda
output -amnd
```

```
import java.util.*;
class uniquechars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string:");
        String str = inp.nextLine();               // input from user
        String res="";
        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<res.length();j++){
                if(str.charAt(i)==res.charAt(j)){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==0){
                res = res+str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Output string with only unique characters:"+res);

    }   
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at uniquechars.main(Main.java:6)
```

Comment: add the runtime error that you are getting.

Comment: I have added the error please see

Comment: @Nishtha - did you try entering something in the console?

Comment: Yes I tried but unable to enter in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any online tool to test your code, be sure to provide input to the program.
My guess is you are forgetting to give the input to the program while running it on an online tool.

Comment: its not working still getting the same error

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/ide I am running over here please see

Comment: @Nishtha edited my answer. In the tool you mentioned, there is a checkbox on the lower right corner (says: Custom input). Check that checkbox and provide your input. Your program should be working then.

Answer (score 1):

It works on [codechef.com/ide](http://codechef.com/ide), you just have to select your programming language from the dropdown list. as shown here.

[image]